# Postgresql count unique conversation

Tags: postgresql

Hello i have some table like this:

```
Text | from | to    
A    | 1    | 2     
B    | 2    | 1     
C    | 3    | 1 
D    | 1    | 4
```

And i would like to get number of conversations, so for this example it should be 3. Do anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

One more information - i decided to use UUID so i switched to PostgreSQL and there is no least and greatest.

Comment: One way is with LEAST and GREATEST. It's a no-brainer, so I'll leave you to figure out the details.

Comment: From your data, it looks "conversations" refers to "from" column. In that case, if you use, select count(1) from <table> group by from will do it. Provide your requirements correctly to get quick answer

Comment: @priyaraj Plainly, `conversations` refers to both the `from` and the `to` column.

Comment: Well with least and greatest will be problem because my example is not the same as real data. Real IDS are UUID.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM your_table_name name_of_you_like_to_select
    WHERE name_of_you_like_to_select.from = 3`;
You can use some SQL query like this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the asker wishes to know how many distinct pairings there are, ignoring which column order they come in.